# Is it possible to serve multiple discord bot accounts from one discord.py bot system?

Tags: python, api, server, discord, discord.py

I want to have one server, running a bot, and similarly to dyno premium and other bots like that, I was wondering if it was possible to server multiple discord bot tokens in one script, so in the bots system, it has a list of tokens to serve rather than just one bot! Is this even possible?? Should I try and make some form of api? If so does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: If you use threadning/multiprocessing yes

Comment: How do I do that? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're gonna have to at least try to code it yourself, I'm not gonna spoonfeed you the code. You have to make an honest attempt

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup the system using multiprocessing, and it now works! If anyone wants to see how it works, ill put code below:

```
def worker(token):
  ###SOMECODE###


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tokens = []
  with open("tokens.txt") as file:
    for line in file: 
      line = line.strip() #or some other preprocessing
      tokens.append(line) #storing everything in memory!

  for i in tokens:
    print(tokens)
    token = i
    jobs = []
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(token,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    print("OPERATING")
    print(jobs)
```

Comment: the `jobs` list will be always of length 1, you’re re-defining it again in the for-loop, it should be outside of it. Also instead of `token = i ` you can simply do `for token in tokens`